# Cannot resolve method 'setupWithViewPager(androidx.viewPager.widget.ViewPager)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, material-components, material-components-android

I an learning android studio and was trying to make a simple app using fragments but I am getting the below error.

```
error- Cannot resolve method 'setupWithViewPager(androidx.viewPager.widget.ViewPager)'
```

**My Code:**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TableLayout tableLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tableLayout= (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        viewPager=(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager_id);
        adapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.AddFragement(new Fragment_call(),"Call");
        adapter.AddFragement(new FragmentContact(),"Contact");
        adapter.AddFragement(new FragmentFav(),"Favourite");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tableLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

**My gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 29
   buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
   defaultConfig {
   applicationId "com.example.ass"
   minSdkVersion 15
   targetSdkVersion 29
   versionCode 1
   versionName "1.0"
   testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
   release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
   }
}
}

dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
   //compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have also added maven{ url="...."} in the other gradle file.

Comment: Should be a `TabLayout` and not `TableLayout`

Answer (score 2):

Didn't you mean TabLayout instead TableLayout?

If so, change `tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);` to `TabLayout tableLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);`

Answer (score 1):

> `tableLayout= (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);`
>       `tableLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);`

The [`android.widget.TableLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout) doesn't have the method `setupWithViewPager`.

Maybe you are looking for the [**`com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TabLayout.md).

It requires the Material Components library as dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's TabLayout and not TableLayout. These are two different things.